# How to get mating value of a combobox item that comes from access database?

Tags: c#, database, combobox, windows-forms-designer

im new here and c#.

My question is i got an access database. First column includes names. second one includes their values. for example first column is "names" and second column is "weight". If I select "michael" from combobox i want to reach his weight. then his weight data will go on a mathematical formula. and the result will be printed on screen.

How can i do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've filled the database data into a datatable with something like:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
using(var da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select Name, Weight from person", "some connection string here")
  da.Fill(dt);
```

You can make the combo show the names and give the values with:

```
yourCombo.DisplayMember = "Name";
yourCombo.ValueMember = "Weight";
yourCombo.DataSource = dt;
```

And you can then get the selected weight with:

```
var weight = (int)yourCombo.SelectedValue;
```

(Assuming the weight is an integer; if it's something else, change the `(int)` cast to whatever it is)